# Changing the WHERE clause in the Master Detail Template in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans-7, master-detail

I'm creating a small program to use on a research project.  I'm using the Master Detail template in NetBeans and it works fine until I need to add WHERE to the rows retrieved by the Master.  There are a series of Java @ annotations in the Model class that contain queries with WHERE clauses for all of the columns in the result set.  For example

@NamedQueries({
   @NamedQuery(name = "Topic.findByTopicId", query = "SELECT t FROM Topic t WHERE t.topicIc = :topicId"),

There is a whole set of those.  That is what I want to use but I can't find how to set the query.  The query is set in code that I'm unable to change because NetBeans created and has frozen it.

query = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Topic t");

There is also a persistence.xml file that NetBeans creates that has the JDBC connect information and the name of the Model class.

I have nearly 15 years of experience using Java but always as either command line or back end but never GUI.  This seemed like a quick way to get my project going but if I can't change it, I need to find a different solution.  Can anyone explain how to change the query used by the EntityManager?

Answer (score 0):

You can access it this way in Netbeans 7.2: 
click on "Design", then on one of the elements of your design (doesn't matter which one), then the right mouse key. In the popup menu, choose "customize code...". A dialog named "Code customizer" will appear. In the top left, choose "query". Below, instead of "default code", choose "custom creation". There you will be able to edit your initialization code.